# When I replace one list with another list, something goes wrong

Tags: python, list, file

I'm doing an assignment in which I have to make a Hangman game. I just started from scratch using my very basic knowledge. A lot of things might be more efficient in a different way, but I enjoy figuring out my own solutions. So here is my code. The idea is that I want to switch from one list to another list. But when I do the rest of the code fails, where it worked before.

```
import random
alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')                 

allwords = []                                                                               

with open('google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-long.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        allwords.append(line.strip().split(','))
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut']                                                                  

word = random.choice(words)                                                                 

guessesleft = 8                                                                             
sentence1 = ('You have %d guesses!\n') % guessesleft                                        

length = len(word)                                          
uslist = ['_'] * length                                                                     

hangword = list(word)
```

The problem is as follows: In the code, currently 'words' is used and that works. However, now instead of using 'words' as a list of words, I want to use the textfile and 'allwords' as a list of words (so I change word=random.choice(words) in word=random.choice(allwords). It does select a random word from the file, but after that it goes wrong. Every word only produces on '_' instead of 1 for every letter in the randomly chosen word. Are my lists different? How do I fix this?

Comment: Indent your code. It's Python, it makes no sense wrongly indented.

Comment: You want `allwords.extend(...`, not `allwords.append(...`.  As it is, `allwords` isn't a list of words (like `words` was), it's a list of lists of words.

Comment: @Mikael, I am not sure what you mean. Apart from the blank lines (I really have no idea why they are there) this is exactly the same code, with the same indentations as in my text editor.

Comment: @ jasonsharper Thank you so much, that solved my problem. I guess I should have known better than to implement something of which I do not fully understand what it does ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using the split function?

```
allwords.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

The split() function returns a list of items separated by the delimiter so even in a string without the delimiter, the function will return a list

```
"helloworld".split(",")   # returns ["helloworld"]
```

If you only want the first element after the split, you can use:

```
allwords.append(line.strip().split(',')[0])
```

Comment: The reason for the split is honestly incomplete comprehension of the function. I thought that it did exactly what I wanted, turns out it did not. The solution commented by @jasonharper did though. But as I understand now, the split is unnecessary. Thank you for taking the time to answer!